# FULLTEXT search with multiple exact phrases and exclusions

Tags: mysql, boolean, full-text-search

I'm trying to create a fulltext query that matches ANY of multiple exact phrases and excluding others. In my test query. I want to select any record that has EITHER (or both) the exact phrase 'brown cow' OR 'green cat' AND NOT 'silver rhino'. I have set up test records with combinations of these three phrases and should return 3 records if I can get my query right.

Query 1
SELECT * FROM jos_sea_messages
WHERE ((Match(body,subject) Against('"+green cat"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR Match(body,subject) Against('"+brown cow"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) 
AND ( Match(body,subject) Against('"-silver rhino"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)))

Returns 2 records- one of them with 'silver rhino', so not what I want

Query 2
SELECT * FROM jos_sea_messages
WHERE ((Match(body,subject) Against('"+green cat"  "-silver rhino"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR Match(body,subject) Against('"+brown cow" "-silver rhino"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)))
Returns all records with any of the phrases, including 'silver rhino', so still not right

Query 3
SELECT * FROM jos_sea_messages
WHERE (Match(body,subject) Against('"+green cat" "+brown cow" "-silver rhino"' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
Returns a whole lot of rows, some of which I don't think have any of the exact phrases?

What is the proper syntax for finding records that have either (or both) exact phrases 'brown cow' and 'green cat' but must not contain 'silver rhino'?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Here is my query:
SELECT * FROM jos_sea_messages WHERE (Match(body,subject) Against('"green cat" "brown cow" -"silver rhino"' IN BOOLEAN MODE))

The + aren't required because that would mean that both phrases were needed, and the - goes outside the double quotes.

Hope it helps someone else. I'm sure this type of requirement isn't unique